# Intento de Conexion entre JTable y MySQL JAVA NETBEANS 8.2

Tags: java, mysql, jframe, netbeans-8.2, jtable

Tengo un JFrame donde esta un JTable con un boton para que cargue la tabla que esta en MYSQL con datos pero me sale el error de:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError,etc (esto cuando le doy al boton de cargar)

Ya tengo la conexion exitosa en un JFrame con botones para ingresar,elimnar,modificar datos a mySQL pero lo que quiero ahora es que muestre los datos que estan en mySQL en un JTable pero no me deja, porfavor ayuda soy un toque nuevo en esto, si quiere que pase codigo del btnCargar me dicen

---

Me hace falta la libreria que tu tienes encerrada en un circulo

Ya pude ver como se envia el codigo
Este seria:

*CONECTOR:*

```
  package Acceso;

  import java.sql.*;
  import javax.swing.*;


  public class Conector 
   {
    String driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_parqueo"; 
    String user="root"; 
    String pwd="";

    public ResultSet Listar(String Cad)
   {try{ 

    Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
    Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd); 
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(Cad); 
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); 
    return rs; 
}
catch(Exception e)
{ 

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage()); 
    return null; 
       } 
   }

     public void Ejecutar(String Cad)
     { int r;

try
    { 
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance(); 
    Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pwd); 
    PreparedStatement ps = cn.prepareStatement(Cad); 

    r=ps.executeUpdate(); 
    
    if(r>0)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"COMANDO EJECUTADO","GRACIAS", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    
    
     }catch(Exception e){ 
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.getMessage()); 

     
  
     } 
       } 
    public Connection getConexion() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); 
          //To 
   change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
   }
```

}

*GETTERS Y SETTERS*

```
 package Implementacion;
 import Acceso.Conector;

public class Auto 
 {   

 private String placa,marca,estado;
 private int año;


public Auto() {
}

public Auto(String placa, String marca, String estado, int año) {
    this.placa = placa;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.estado = estado;
    this.año = año;
}


//Metodos acceso get-set
public String getPlaca() {
    return placa;
}

public void setPlaca(String placa) {
    this.placa = placa;
}

public String getMarca() {
    return marca;
}

public void setMarca(String marca) {
    this.marca = marca;
}

public String getEstado() {
    return estado;
}

public void setEstado(String estado) {
    this.estado = estado;
}

public int getAño() {       
    return año;
}
                      
public void setAño(int año) {
    this.año = año;
}
```

*MI JFRAME DE JTABLE*

```
package Formulario;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

 public class Tabla_Autos extends javax.swing.JFrame {


public Tabla_Autos() {
    setLocationRelativeTo(this);
    initComponents();
   
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    tb_autos = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    btnCargar = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    txtCampo = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    tb_autos.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 255));
    tb_autos.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new 
    java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0)));
    tb_autos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null},
            {null, null, null, null}
        },
        new String [] {
            "Placa", "Marca", "Anio", "Estado"
        }
    ) {
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class
        };
        boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
            false, false, false, false
        };

        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }

        public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return canEdit [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tb_autos);

    getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(33, 106, -1, 100));

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

    btnCargar.setText("Cargar");
    btnCargar.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            btnCargarActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jLabel2.setText("Codigo");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(32, 32, 32)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addComponent(txtCampo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 217, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 46, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(btnCargar)
            .addGap(99, 99, 99))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(49, 49, 49)
                    .addComponent(btnCargar))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(txtCampo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap(389, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 520, 470));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void btnCargarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

    
    try{
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
        tb_autos.setModel(modelo);
        
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs =  null;
        Conexion conn = new Conexion();
        Connection cn = conn.getConexion();
        
        String sql = "Select placa,marca,anio,estado from tb_auto";
        ps = (PreparedStatement) cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        
        ResultSetMetaData rsMd = rs.getMetaData(); //pasando el resultado de la consulta
        int cantidadColumnas = rsMd.getColumnCount();
        
        modelo.addColumn("Placa");
        modelo.addColumn("Marca");
        modelo.addColumn("Anio");
        modelo.addColumn("Estado");
        
        while (rs.next()){
            
            Object[] filas = new Object[cantidadColumnas];
            
            //paar pasar todos los datos a todo el objeto
            for(int i=0; i<cantidadColumnas; i++)
            {
                filas[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
            modelo.addRow(filas);
            }
        
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.err.println(e.toString());
    }
}                                         


public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabla_Autos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabla_Autos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabla_Autos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Tabla_Autos.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Tabla_Autos().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton btnCargar;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JTable tb_autos;
private javax.swing.JTextField txtCampo;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

No se si me podrias seguir ayudando para poder solucionar mi erro, gracias por haber respondido a mi repsuesta

Comment: De hecho, _debes_ colocar un [repro] en la pregunta, ya que sin código es muy difícil ayudarte. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Lo útil en este caso también sería mostrar el porqué de la excepción (la línea que dice `Caused by:`) ya que da pistas de lo que podría estar sucediendo. No olvides modificar el título para mencionar el problema en específico que estás teniendo.

Answer (score 0):

hola como no haz compartido tu codigo te compartire el mio con explicacion del boton cargar.

primero agrega las librerias a tu proyecto de mysql
[image: imagen de librerias mysql]

luego tenes que crear una conexion  a mysql con tu usuario ROOT y contraseña
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

agrega estas librerias:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
```

luego prepara la conexion a tu base de datos:

```
public class Conexion {
    Connection con;
    public Conexion(){
        try {
//            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
//            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-G868REJ:1433;databaseName=ejemplobd;IntegratedSecurity=true;");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rentacar?useTimeZone=true&serverTimezone=UTC&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false","root","ventilador_2200");
        
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: \n"+e.getClass()+"\n"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public Connection getConnection(){
        
       
        return con;
        
    }
    
}
```

tambien tienes que crear un modelo de la tabla en neatbeans eh incluir setter y getter:

```
package modelo;

/**
 *
 * @author jony_
 */
public class Autos {
    int IdAuto;
    String Marca;
    int Año;
    int Codigo;
    String TipoAuto;
    String Placa;
    int TarjetaCirculacion;
    String Modelo;
    double Precio;
    String Estado;

    public int getIdAuto() {
        return IdAuto;
    }

    public void setIdAuto(int IdAuto) {
        this.IdAuto = IdAuto;
    }

    public String getMarca() {
        return Marca;
    }

    public void setMarca(String Marca) {
        this.Marca = Marca;
    }

    public int getAño() {
        return Año;
    }

    public void setAño(int Año) {
        this.Año = Año;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return Codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(int Codigo) {
        this.Codigo = Codigo;
    }

    public String getTipoAuto() {
        return TipoAuto;
    }

    public void setTipoAuto(String TipoAuto) {
        this.TipoAuto = TipoAuto;
    }

    public String getPlaca() {
        return Placa;
    }

    public void setPlaca(String Placa) {
        this.Placa = Placa;
    }

    public int getTarjetaCirculacion() {
        return TarjetaCirculacion;
    }

    public void setTarjetaCirculacion(int TarjetaCirculacion) {
        this.TarjetaCirculacion = TarjetaCirculacion;
    }

    public String getModelo() {
        return Modelo;
    }

    public void setModelo(String Modelo) {
        this.Modelo = Modelo;
    }

    public double getPrecio() {
        return Precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(double Precio) {
        this.Precio = Precio;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return Estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String Estado) {
        this.Estado = Estado;
    }

    
           
}
```

para listar los elemntos realiza la consulta desde neatbeans a mysql de esta manera:
usando un select * from este los recibira y los almacenara con los setters del modelo
de autos que realizas la intancia:

```
public List tablaDesdeMYSQL(){
        List<Autos> ListaDeCarro = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            con = conectar.getConnection();
            ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM autos");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Autos NueoCarro2 = new Autos();
                
                NueoCarro2.setIdAuto(rs.getInt(1));
                NueoCarro2.setMarca(rs.getString(2));
                NueoCarro2.setAño(rs.getInt(3));
                NueoCarro2.setCodigo(rs.getInt(4));
                NueoCarro2.setTipoAuto(rs.getString(5));
                NueoCarro2.setPlaca(rs.getString(6));
                NueoCarro2.setTarjetaCirculacion(rs.getInt(7));
                NueoCarro2.setModelo(rs.getString(8));
                NueoCarro2.setPrecio(rs.getDouble(9));
                NueoCarro2.setEstado(rs.getString(10));
                
   
                ListaDeCarro.add(NueoCarro2);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return ListaDeCarro;
    }
```

**luego envias los elementos a tu tabla desde el boton cargar con el siguiente codigo:
aclaro que para el JTABLE necesitas crear un MODELO que recibe el JTABLE como se observa en el siguiente codigo, el jtable que es el nombre de tu tabla es el que necesitas enviar:**

```
public void listar(JTable tabla){
         int contador2=0;
        modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tabla.getModel();//aqui obtenemos el modelo de las columnas de las JTABLE

    
        tabla.setModel(modelo);//esta linea envia toda la informacion a la tabla
        
        
        List<Autos> lista = operCarro.tablaDesdeMYSQL();//aqui traemos los datos desde OPERUSARIO la lista de datos
        
        Object[] objeto = new Object[10];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
            contador2=contador2+1;
            objeto[0] = lista.get(i).getIdAuto();
            objeto[1] = lista.get(i).getMarca();
            objeto[2] = lista.get(i).getAño();
            objeto[3] = lista.get(i).getCodigo();
            objeto[4] = lista.get(i).getTipoAuto();
            objeto[5] = lista.get(i).getPlaca();
            objeto[6] = lista.get(i).getTarjetaCirculacion();
            objeto[7] = lista.get(i).getModelo();
            objeto[8] = lista.get(i).getPrecio();
            objeto[9] = lista.get(i).getEstado();
            
            
            modelo.addRow(objeto);
        }
         
    }
```

Comment: Espera a que el OP (autor de la pregunta) actualice su pregunta para dar más detalles. ¡Diste un ejemplo extenso sin haber visto el código del OP! Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.